# Haskell's type system treats a numerical value as function?

Tags: haskell, types, numeric, typeclass

After playing around with haskell a bit I stumbled over this function:

```
Prelude Data.Maclaurin> :t ((+) . ($) . (+))
((+) . ($) . (+)) :: (Num a) => a -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
```

(Data.Maclaurin is exported by the package vector-space.) So it takes a Num, a function, another Num and ultimately returns a Num. What magic makes the following work?

```
Prelude Data.Maclaurin> ((+) . ($) . (+)) 1 2 3
6
```

2 is obviously not a function (a->a) or did I miss out on something?

Comment: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Num_instance_for_functions

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [`Data.NumInstances`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector-space/0.6.0/doc/html/src/Data-NumInstances.html) module of the same package [defines](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector-space/0.6.0/doc/html/src/Data-NumInstances.html#line-39) a `Num` instance for functions that return numbers:

```
instance Num b => Num (a->b) where
  (+)         = liftA2 (+)
  (*)         = liftA2 (*)
  fromInteger = pure . fromInteger
  ...
```

In Haskell an integer literal like `2` is generic so that it can represent a number for any instance of `Num`:

```
Prelude> :t 2
2 :: (Num t) => t
```

To convert it to an actual number of the type required in a specific context, `fromInteger` from the `Num` class is called.

Since the helper module mentioned above defines an instance of `Num` for functions, *`2` can now be converted to a function* with the `fromInteger` method specified there.
So ghci calls `fromInteger 2` to get the function required as the second parameter of the construct in the question. The whole expression then happens to evaluate to `6`.

Comment: Moreover, *all* applicative functors admit these instances for the numeric classes. See the [applicative-numbers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/applicative-numbers) package for an easy way to define such instances for whatever applicative functor you want.

Answer (score 1):

You have good reason to be confused. Using the `Data.NumInstances` module in GHC (which is loaded by `Data.Maclaurin`) it is possible to coerce a `Num` to a constant function.

```
Prelude Data.NumInstances> :t (2 :: (Num a) => a -> a)
(2 :: (Num a) => a -> a) :: (Num a) => a -> a
Prelude Data.NumInstances> (2 :: (Num a) => a -> a) 0          
2
Prelude Data.NumInstances> (2 :: (Num a) => a -> a) 1000
2
```

The evaluation of the expression is, essentially,

```
((+) . ($) . (+)) 1 2 3 = ((+) . ($) . (1+)) 2 3
                        = ((+) (1+)) 2 3
                        -- (+) is defined for functions that return a Num
                        = ((+) (1+) (\_ -> 2)) 3  
                        = ((+2) . (1+)) 3
                        = 6
```

Comment: No it's not possible, unless you have some nonstandard modules loaded which define a `Num` instance for `a -> a`.

Comment: Well, damn, I could swear this worked without Data.Maclaurin loaded, but it doesn't. As @sth points out, this magic is enabled by Data.NumInstances.